# Jquery select all rows, not just the ones greater than zero

Tags: jquery, html

I have this piece of Jquery code

```
$("#reconciliation-grid").find('tr:gt(0)').each(function (queueIndex, queueItem)
```

I want to change it so that it finds *all* tr, not just tr greater than the zeroth row. Can I just change it to find('tr')?

Comment: `Yes you can` would be the answer for your question

Comment: "I want to change it to find all the <td> tags, can I do that? How about all <div> tags? How about ...." YES!

Answer (score 1):

jQuery uses CSS Selectors.

**So, You can try:**

```
$("#reconciliation-grid tr").each(function (i,e){

}
```

For  `td` you can do it this way:

```
   $(function(){

        $('#reconciliation-grid tr td').each(function(i,e){

            $(e).css({border:'3px solid red'})// This will give a Red 3px Solid Border to all "td" elements

})

        })
```

This supposing that your `<table id = "reconciliation-grid">`